# View does not display attached file without Display field checked

Tags: 7, views

I've got a view that exposes a list of nodes with fields: Title, Publishing date, Attached files.

If an attached file has checked the "Display" flag it is visible on the view result, but if the "Display" field is not checked the file is not visible.

Is it possible to show all attached files?

[image: This is the resut of my view, what user see]

[image: And this are files attached to node]

There are three files attached to node, but only two with "Display" checked, I'll want to show all files attached to node.

Answer (score 0):

Under advanced > query settings > check "Disable SQL rewriting" - it should prevent any access or visibility checks for nodes and fields. Don't forget to add the ones you need directly to a view if you do this.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DavideRimerici sorry to hear that. It might help if you would have answered sooner. It's over a week now and I don't really have the tabs I used to research your issue open now. Not even in browser's history. Good luck finding an answer.